# UI Bug Transforming code from Blazor Server to Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, css, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am currently trying to move a razor file from my Blazor Server project into a Blazor WASM project. However, when I run the razor file on the WASM project, the UI becomes strange as below:

[image]

There is always a white space below the background image, which I inserted in the body tag:

```
<body style="background-image: url('StarBackground.jpg'); background-size:cover;">
...
<body>
```

And below is how I configure the `MainLayout.razor`:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>Tarotpersonality</PageTitle>

<div>
    <div>
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this issue?

In addition, the image sizes seem to change as I run the razor file in Blazor WASM...

Comment: Try this css please: `style="background-image: url('StarBackground.jpg'); no-repeat #yourBackgroundColorCode center`

Comment: `style="background: url('StarBackground.jpg') no-repeat; background-size: cover; height: 100vh; padding: 0; margin: 0;"`